# How to get the total count of unique terms on aggregations with the size set?

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, elasticsearch-aggregation

When using the [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on an ElasticSearch query, the result will limit the buckets to the top 10 items or the value set on the [size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size) parameter. For example:

```json
{
  "aggs" : {
    "cities" : {
      "terms" : { 
        "field" : "city",
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query would give me the top 20 buckets and their counts. How do I change this query to know the total count of unique `"city"` terms, so I can present something like "*showing the top 20 cities of 73*"?

Comment: Although it may not be obvious, the [Filtering Values with partitions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) section of the `terms aggregations` documentation may answer this question, where it says _"Use the cardinality aggregation to estimate the total number of unique account_id values"_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) can be requested on the same query. So on the provided example, we would have:

```json
{
  "aggs" : {
    "cities" : {
      "terms" : { 
        "field" : "city",
        "size": 20
      }
    },
    "unique_cities": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "city"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the `"aggregations"` response would have, besides the `"cities"` element (which contains the `buckets`), the `"unique_cities"` element with the cardinality:

```json
"unique_cities": {
  "value": 73
}
```

---

Credits to this issue on github:
[Return number of buckets for terms aggregation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7585)

Comment: Cardinality aggregation will return approximate numbers. So the results will be approximation instead of exact count. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

average rating and total rating count

```
GET /user_data_factory/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "avgRating": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "rating"
      }
    },
   "count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "rating"
      }
    }
  }
}
```